# Display a huge file on GUI

Tags: python, django, large-files

I am very new to programming world. I have started learning Python. I am trying to develop a program that gets user input, runs some commands in the background and then display the output on web interface. Although it is little more complex, but for simplicity, you can consider this as:

1. user enters a filename
2. python code runs "cat filename"
3. output is displayed on the screen.

I have Python + Django + Apache setup. I am using HTML to to display the output. It is working fine as long as the output being returned is reasonably small. But sometimes I have huge output (~700 MB) and obviously I am having difficulty displaying it on web interface.

```
Code Snippet:
op = subprocess.check_output(cmd,universal_newlines=True)
return render (request, 'display.html', {'op': op})
```

What is the best approach to display such large content on web? Some points I wanted to put on the table:

- Store the output in a file rather than a string. Read the file in chunks.In this case, can I have my code write to the file and read the file for display simultaneously? I don't think it is a good idea but wanted to check.
- Are there any python packages intended to resolve such problem? Any django feature?
- When I have huge output, it takes a while for the program to get the output and then it takes a while to be displayed on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't display 700 MB of alphanumerical data at once on any regular screen and even if you could, a user would drown in it. So you should display portions and enable scrolling or selection. As you indicate, loading all this data costs quite some time. But since you don't view it in one piece, you also don't have to load it in one piece. Rather than refreshing your whole page you should use Ajax (as e.g. implemented in jQuery) to have the browser load your data into an appropriate HTML/DOM element in portions as indicated by the user who e.g. shifts a scrollbar. Given the fact that 700 MB even in that case is just too much, a better way would be to select data for display using some type of hierarchical (tree) control or another non-sequential selection mechanism. The only task of Django in this case, apart from serving the page itself, is serving the requested data portion, e.g. as JSON data. As mentioned the page holding both the displayed data portion and the selection controls is served only once.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at some of the jQuery Infinite Scrolling options [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-infinite-scrolling-demos/).